# Inject field from @QuarkusTestResource and access from BeforeEachCallback of custom junit extension

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I have a `@QuarkusTestResource` that injects a field into my test.
The field happens to be a client which needs to be connected before a test and disconnected after each test.

```
@QuarkusTestResource(MyTestResource.class)
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {

  @ClientInject
  TestMqttClient testClient

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    testClient.connect();
  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
    testClient.disconnect();
  }

  ...
}
```

To not have to connect/diconnect in a boilerplate `@BeforEach`/`@AfterEach`, I would like to extract this to a jUnit extension with a `BeforeEachCallback`/`AfterEachCallback`.

```
@QuarkusTestResource(MyTestResource.class)
@ExtendWith(ConnectClientExtension.class)
@QuarkusTest
class MyTest {

  @ClientInject
  TestMqttClient testClient

  @Test
  void myTest() {
    testClient.doStuff();
  }

}
```

While my extension does the following magic:

```
public class ConnectMqttClientInterceptor implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback{

    private Optional<TestMqttClient> getTestMqttClient(ExtensionContext context) {
        Optional<Method> testMqttClientGetter =
                findRecursive(context.getRequiredTestClass());
        return testMqttClientGetter.map(method -> {
            try {
                if(!method.trySetAccessible()){
                    throw new IllegalAccessError("Cannot access TestMqttClient field");
                }
                Object testInstance = getTestInstance(context, method);
                return (TestMqttClient) method.invoke(testInstance);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalAccessError();
            }
        });
    }

    private Object getTestInstance(ExtensionContext context, Method method) {
        Class<?> targetClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
        Optional<Object> targetTestInstance = context.getRequiredTestInstances().getAllInstances().stream().filter(instance -> instance.getClass().equals(targetClass)).collect(QumeaCollectors.getSingleElement());
        return targetTestInstance.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Could not find testinstance for class "+ targetClass.getCanonicalName()));
    }

    private Optional<Method> findRecursive(Class<?> clazz) {
        Method[] declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        Optional<Method> testMqttClientGetter = Stream.of(declaredMethods)
                .filter(method -> method.getReturnType().equals(TestMqttClient.class))
                .collect(QumeaCollectors.getSingleElement());
        if (testMqttClientGetter.isEmpty() && clazz.getEnclosingClass() != null) {
            return findRecursive(clazz.getEnclosingClass());
        }
        return testMqttClientGetter;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Optional<TestMqttClient> testMqttClient = getTestMqttClient(context);
        testMqttClient.ifPresent(TestMqttClient::connect);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {  
        Optional<TestMqttClient> testMqttClient = getTestMqttClient(context);          
        testMqttClient.ifPresent(TestMqttClient::disconnect);
    }
}
```

When my jUnit extension is executing its `BeforeEachCallback`, the field `testClient` of my test instance still seems to be `null`. Is this beacuse the test instance which I receive within my jUnit extension is not the bean that actually holds the injected field or is the junit extension just beeing executed too early??

In general, is it possible to access a `TestInjector` injected field from a jUnit `BeforeEachCallback` in a `@QuarkusTest`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is a classloading issue, similar to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/27821. In the course of executing a JUnit test, the class will be accessed through two different classloaders. The second classloader is what creates the `@QuarkusTest` magic, such as injection. Since there's two classloaders, that can create some inconsistencies in edge cases. The JUnit Extension may be one of those edge cases.

So far, the JUnit API hasn't had the endpoints which would let Quarkus tell JUnit what classloader should be used for test classes, but there's a promising-looking endpoint in JUnit 5.10. (Once that's released, Quarkus may be able to update its test engine to avoid the classloading problems.)

For this use case, however, could you relax the requirement that setup and teardown (connection and disconnection) be done before each test method. If so, I think you could get away with what's already in Quarkus, with no need for a custom JUnit extension. As others have suggested, with that relaxed requirement, a `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` in combination with `@QuarkusTestResource` would be invoked by the framework at the right(ish) time (once per test).

Answer (score -1):

I did some similar yesterday to integrate wiremock in my tests using [`QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource):

```
public class Wiremock implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    WireMockServer server;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        this.server = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options().port(9001));
        server.start();
        return Map.of();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.server.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(TestInjector testInjector) {
        testInjector.injectIntoFields(server, new TestInjector.MatchesType(WireMockServer.class));
    }
}
```

and my test

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(MercurioApiGatewayWiremock.class)
@TestHTTPEndpoint(ForwardAccessTokensToMercurioFilterTest.TestResource.class)
class ForwardAccessTokensToMercurioFilterTest
{
    WireMockServer wiremock;

    @Test
    @TestSecurity
    void testFilter()
    {
        wiremock.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/public/login"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .withBody("""
                                {
                                    "accessToken" : "access-token",
                                    "refreshToken" : "refresh-token"
                                }
                                """)));
        RestAssured.given()
                .post("login")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Add `@BeforeEach` and/or `@AfterEach` in test class as you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to inject value to a field of a test class you sould use implement `inject` mehtod of `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`.

`QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback` allows to access injected field.

The following example injects a `TestClient` instance to an annotated field and beforeEach callback calls some method on the injected instance (e.g. re-init the TestClient instance)

```java
public class TestClientInjector implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager, QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

    }

    @Override
    public void inject(Object testInstance) {

        // org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils;
        findAnnotatedFields(
                testInstance.getClass(),
                ClientTest.class,
                f -> f.getType().isAssignableFrom(TestMqClient.class))
                .forEach(f -> {
                    try {
                        injectValue(f, testInstance);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });

    }

    private void injectValue(Field field, Object testInstance) throws IllegalAccessException {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        // initiate instance somehow (e.g. using Arc.container())
        var clientInstance = new TestMqClient();
        // set value
        field.set(testInstance, clientInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(QuarkusTestMethodContext context) {
        findAnnotatedFields(
                context.getTestInstance().getClass(),
                ClientTest.class,
                (f) -> f.getType().isAssignableFrom(TestMqClient.class)
        ).forEach(f -> {
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                TestMqClient clientField = (TestMqClient) f.get(context.getTestInstance());
                if (null != clientField) {
                    // do something what needed
                    clientField.clearClient();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to clear client " + f.getName(), e);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The dummy test client

```java
public class TestMqClient {

    public void clearClient() {
        System.out.println("Clearing client");
    }
}
```

An example test:

```java
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(TestClientInjector.class)
class SomeTest {

    @ClientTest
    TestMqClient client;

    @Test
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("run");
        assertNotNull(client);
    }
}
```

After the test run the output looks like:

```
2023-06-07 11:46:44,039 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-reactive, hibernate-reactive-panache, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
Clearing client
run
2023-06-07 11:46:44,124 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-scheduler-vertx stopped in 0.031s
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to register the callback in `META-INF/services/io.quarkus.test.junit.callback.QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback`